# How to apply nth-child to tables generated from database

Tags: php, css

I'm having trouble setting up some css code for a table I'm generating using php from a database. I want every even row to have a different background-color, so I tried using nth-child(even) for this, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Here's my code:
style.css:

```
#usertable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
}
#usertable td, #usertable th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(228,227,227);
    padding: 8px;
}
#usertable tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: rgb(115,115,115);}
```

admin.php:

```
<table id="usertable">
    <tr>
        <th> Id: </th>
        <th> Username: </th>
        <th> Rights: </th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $userquery = "SELECT id, username, strength FROM users";
        $result = $conn->query($userquery) or die($conn->error);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
                    <td>
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" name="newrights" value=" <?php echo $row['strength']; ?> ">
                        <input type="text" name="idnumber" hidden="true" value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?> ">
                        <input type="text" name="usertochange" hidden="true" value=" <?php echo $row['username']; ?> ">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some markup error with your code

```
<table id="usertable">
<tr> <!--Add this-->
<th> Id: </th>
<th> Username: </th>
<th> Rights: </th>
</tr> <!--Add this-->
<?php
    $userquery = "SELECT id, username, strength FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($userquery) or die($conn->error);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>";
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
                <input type=\"number\" min=\"0\" max=\"255\" name=\"newrights\" value=\"" . $row['strength'] . "\">
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"idnumber\" hidden=\"true\" value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">
                <input type=\"text\" name=\"usertochange\" hidden=\"true\" value=\"" . $row['username'] . "\">
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\">
            </form></td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Also looks like you have used many slaces so i suggest you to check table markup on browser

***Updated: Add***

```
#usertable td:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #efefef;}
```

Do not use tr as you have given background color to td and th initially

Comment: Yea the <tr> and </tr> tag were missing, but this didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Add this `#usertable td:nth-child(odd){background-color: rgb(115,115,115);}`

Comment: Ah yes, this works, thanks! And as this is the easiest solution I'll use this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sue some CSS class in each alternate table row?

Ex:

**HTML**

```
<tr class="bg-red">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>

<tr class="bg-blue">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-blue{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .bg-red{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

I think this will simplify your code & make it easy to read.

**Example for Dynamic Data**

```
<?php
    $users[] = array('fname'=>'Jill', 'lname'=>'Smith', 'age'=>50);
    $users[] = array('fname'=>'Eve', 'lname'=>'Jackson', 'age'=>94);

    $rowColClass = 'bg-blue';
    foreach ($users as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<tr class='$rowColClass'>";
            echo "<td>$value[fname]</td>";
            echo "<td>$value[lname]</td>";
            echo "<td>$value[age]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        if($rowColClass == 'bg-blue')
            $rowColClass = 'bg-red';
        else
            $rowColClass = 'bg-blue';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes this would work if I hardcoded the table, but I get the table from a database. So I don't know the results in advance.

Comment: For sake of example, I've hard coded that. But If you want, you can dynamically through PHP append the class in each row.

Comment: @BobRuiken Added a sample code for Dynamic data. Maybe that will do some help to you.

Comment: I don't know if this could have been solved easier, but I got this working by adding a counter and performing a $counter%2==0 check on each row. Thanks!

Comment: That'll also work fine. There thousand way to solve that problem  & you've chosen one. All the best